# How can I retrieve the published Artifacts from Artifactory into my jenkins pipeline script

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

I try to get the list of published Artifacts from my deploy onto my Artifactory.

I tried to do so over the `BuildInfoAccessor`, but the current version is lacking the `getDeployedArtifacts()` function.

I even tried to read the jenkins build.log object, but it somehow misses the prints from `artifactory-plugin` on which artifacts are deployed.

Can someone give me a hint on where to look at or an example ?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve, but if I understand you correctly you need the build info that the Jenkins Artifactory plugin is generating by default.

Answer (score 1):

Am not sure is there any better way to print the BuildInfo from the artifactory-jenkins plugin itself. You can get the published info of the jenkins build via artifactory rest api.
[Artifactory Rest Api](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API)

You can get the build number from the jenkins environment variable `${BUILD_NUMBER}` and make a http get call via sh curl/other suitable step if any in your pipeline script.

```
sh "curl http://artifactory.org.net/api/build/my-build/${BUILD_NUMBER}"
```

Make use of `withCredential` step to pass username/password.

Caution: I have just made answers from my theoretical knowledge.